# How to change the touchUi property on mat-datepicker in Angular Material

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 5 with the Material Design modules.

In my html, I have a datepicker:

```
<mat-datepicker touchUi=true #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

In my CSS I set up some media queries:

```
/* Phones */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
}

/* Tablets */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
}

/* Desktops */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
}
```

How can I remove the `touchUi=true` property for desktops?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use Angular CDK's `BreakpointObserver` to do that, as well as with getters.

1. Import `LayoutModule` from `@angular/cdk/layout` in your app's module:

   ```ts
   import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
   // ...

   @NgModule({
       imports: [
           LayoutModule
       ]
   ```
2. Use the breakpoint observer from `@angular/cdk/layout` as follows (you probably want the `isMatched` method of `BreakpointObserver` which allows a `string` or `string[]` as its param for the media):

   ```ts
   import { BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
   export class AppComponent {
       constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver){}
       // Check if device is phone or tablet
       get isMobile() {
           return this.breakpointObserver.isMatched('(max-width: 767px)');
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use it as follows in your datepicker:

   ```html
   <mat-datepicker [touchUi]="isMobile" #picker></mat-datepicker>
   ```

   - [Official documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview#breakpointobserver)
   - [API Docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/api)
   - [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdk-breakpoint-observer-so)

Comment: Thanks! I was already looking into @angular/flex-layout so I ended up injecting ObservableMedia instead of BreakPointObserver. Works the same for the rest of the code.

Comment: Without the mat-datepicker in the view, the getters in Home Component do not change when window is resized. But with it, it works like magic, dark magic. I guess the datepicker is triggering some events, could anyone give more detailed explanation?

Comment: mat-datepicker is one of them making it work, tooltip and menu also has the same effect.

Comment: I guess my question is: how do I get the getters working without any material components in the view?

Comment: I got it. Just need to add an event for window:resize, dont have to do anything for the event, but it triggers change detection and make the getters work.

Comment: @Rex Hmm... Maybe it's something to do with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` or something? (P.S. Sorry for not commenting, didn't see your comment)

Answer (score 5):

Angular uses the `Breakpoints.Handset` methodology:

component.ts:

```
  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver
    .observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(map(result => result.matches));

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}
```

html:

```
<mat-datepicker [touchUi]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'true' : 'false'" #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

Pretty clean way of handling it if you ask me.

If you want a full working example, install the [navigation component schematic](https://material.angular.io/guide/schematics)